# How to move cursor at the end of text of td tag using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys I'm trying to edit a cell inside a table but I'm having cursor issues. This is what I have so far and it doesnt work. The cursor is at begining of a cell no matter what I do. I tried other examples on stackoverflow, but no solution so far. This code comes from a button click event on the same row as this td tag. I'm trying to make table row editable so the user can edit any row by clicking edit button on that particular row.

```
keywords = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
keywords.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
keywords.setAttribute('bgcolor', 'Cyan');
keywords.focus();
moveCursorToEnd(keywords.firstChild);
```

and here is my function:

```
function moveCursorToEnd(obj) {

  if (!(obj.updating)) {
    obj.updating = true;
    var oldValue = obj.value;
    obj.value = '';
    setTimeout(function(){ obj.value = oldValue; obj.updating = false; }, 100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function moveCursorToEnd(input) {
   var originalValue = input.value;
   input.value = "";
   input.blur();
   input.focus();
   input.value = originalValue;
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks Mike.